# https request error on winXP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, web-services, service-reference

i have a c# console application which consumes a webservice (a public webservice of a goverment). To do this, i added a Webservice Reference in my C#-Project, call the appropriate methods and everything works fine on. Except on one PC.

It's a Windows XP SP2 PC, i installed .net framework 4 (which is the target framework of my application). When i call the same commandline-tool here i always get an error message. 100% percent the same tool with same parameters works fine on every other clients (Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, even other Windows XP machines)!?!?!?

Error message:

> Unhandled Exception:  System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An
>   error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https://adress.com/services/TheServiceWSI.
>
> This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not
>   configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case.  This could also
>   be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and
>   the server. 
>   ---> System.Net.WebException:  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

I tried:

- deactivating firewall
- reinstalling .net framwork 4
- deactivating antvir software
- install all windows updates

but no success...

Has anyone an idea what could be the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know you have an invlaid URL there  (second forward slash after address.com) - https://adress.com//services/TheServiceWSI. Just wondering if XP is not as tolerant of that so rt of thing ...

Comment: @CodeUniquely: thank you - was just a typo. edited

Comment: Can you access the WSDL of the service via a browser on the affected PC? Basically I'd suggest looking at the connectivity of a machine that works vs the machine that doesn't. Are the proxy settings the same? Can you intercept traffic via fiddler on both machines and compare? Failing that, run through some of the [suggestions from MS on the issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/915599)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR; Make sure your XP installations are fully patched with SP3 and all the security patches. A lot of SSL/TLS vulnerabilities were patched.*

I recognize this problem, it could be related to the [BEAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#BEAST_attack) vulnerability mitigation (though could as well be one of the other vulnerability patches mentioned in the other answer). After Apple implemented the mitigation on their end with Mavericks, I got similar errors when talking to older Windows services. The reason was related to how packets were fragmented, which triggered errors in implementations that did not exactly follow the spec (apparently Microsoft did not earlier, but they are now).

Either way, you need to drop SP2 and make sure you run SP3.

If you have control over the server, you could try to [disable the BEAST mitigation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/01/21/fixing-the-beast.aspx). According to that post, XP SP3 *should* work with the BEAST mitigation though, so it is probably more of academic interest. Disabling security-related fixes in a production environment is probably not wise.

As you are probably aware of, Windows XP has long passed end of extended support and has gone without security patches for over a year.

Comment: hi , thanks for your answer - i'll check these points. SP3 and .NET FW4 are installed, server is not under my control :/

Comment: thanks a lot! - installing EVERY AVAILABE security update did the trick. Oh how i hate client machines running on "unsupported" OS...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few simple possibilities that you could look into fairly quickly:

1. The question states that the machine is using XP SP2, but that all Windows updates were applied. Are the working XP machines at SP2 or SP3? .NET 4.0 was designed to run on SP3, so if possible in your environment and if you haven't already done so, that would be a prudent update for many reasons.
2. Due to the POODLE vulnerabilities late last year a lot of servers dropped support for SSL 3.0 (and lower) and now require TLS 1.0 or higher. You may want to check in Control Panel / Internet Properties / Advanced / Security to see a list of SSL versions installed and enabled on problem machine and make sure that TLS 1.0 is installed and checked.
3. Check that the system time on the problem machine is about the same as the other machines (that it's not off by too much).

Comment: Point 1: yes SP3 and .NET 4.0
  Point 2 & 3 : thanks ill have a look at this!

Comment: Problem solved (see above) - if i could i would mark you replay as answer too, at least it was very helpful to understand and some important points to check! Thank you very much!